# Regarding relation of multiprocessing with cores of server

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

For the following code, assume I have a 32 core machine, will python decide how many process to create for me?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
for i in range(100):
    p = Process(target=run, args=(fileToAnalyse,))
    p.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not decide for you.

To limit the number of subprocesses, you need to use [a pool of workers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers).

Example from the documentation:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    result = pool.apply_async(f, [10])    # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
    print pool.map(f, range(10))          # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
```

If you omit, `processes=4`, it will use `multiprocessing.cpu_count` which return the number of cpu.